# Doctrine DQL doesn't set ON JOIN automatically

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

I thought if I don't want to override relation's on condition I just use WITH to add an additional condition. I'm not sure if my mapping is wrong, but DQL without join condition in WITH makes a CROSS Join
Here My Entities Relations (Symfony):

Movie:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MovieInterest", mappedBy="movie")
 */
private $movieInterests;
```

MovieInterest:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Movie", inversedBy="movieInterests")
 */
private $movie;
```

Here my Query in MovieInterestRepository:

```
public function deleteByMovieId($id, $user)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $result = $em->createQuery(
        "SELECT mi FROM CineupsWebAppBundle:MovieInterest mi
         JOIN CineupsWebAppBundle:Movie m WITH m.id=mi.movie
            WHERE m.id=".$id." AND mi.user=".$user->getId())
        ->getResult();

    foreach ($result as $entity) {
        $em->remove($entity);
    }

    $em->flush();
}
```

If I remove `WITH m.id=mi.movie` the Query gets too many results

Comment: a little offtopic - your query is `sql-injection` vulnerable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem: I joined with table and not with relation. Here the correct code:

```
"SELECT mi FROM CineupsWebAppBundle:MovieInterest mi
 JOIN mi.movie m
 WHERE m.id=".$id." AND mi.user=".$user->getId())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it this way:

```
$result = $em->getRepository('CineupsWebAppBundle:MovieInterest')
    ->createQuery('mi')
    ->innerJoin('mi.Movie', 'm')
    ->andWhere('m.id = :id')
    ->andWhere('mi.user = :user')
    ->getQuery()
    ->setParameter(':id', $id)
    ->setParameter(':user', $user->getId())
    ->getResult();
```

This will also solve `sqj-injection` vulnerability at your original query

You need to add mapping information to your entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Movie", inversedBy="movieInterests")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="movie")
 */
private $movie;
```

Comment: Thx, I'd like to keep the dql for the moment, as it's a prototype and I have another query which I don't want to change for now. I added the JoinColumn annotation "@ORM\JoinColumn(name="movie_id", referencedColumnName="id")" but it made no difference as it's optional anyway. Maybe It's an intended behaviour when using DQL? I'll switch to query builder later and try

Comment: you can also try to change `WITH` to `ON` at your query - just a blind guess

Comment: I tryed it yesterday, I recon it didn't work. I just would expect the on condition would set automaticaly from my relation mapping. I'll just leave my code as it is and will figure out later

Comment: figured out the solution - see my answer. Your code was already correct